# Disable sitemesh for grails scaffolds?

Tags: grails, scaffolding, sitemesh

How do I disable templating and sitemesh for scaffold-enabled controllers? I want to display the full scaffold here, and my main template is screwing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to rename the layout name used from the scaffolded views. After you did

```
grails install-templates
```

you have the template of the generated scaffolded pages (which you might have used, when you did `grails generate-all *`). In the new folder `src/templates/scaffolding/*.gsp` change the layout name to something like `generatedMain`. I guess you know, but just to be sure:

```
<meta name="layout" content="generatedMain" />
```

Now restore the orginal `main.gsp` and rename it to `generatedMain.gsp`. Then regenerate your scaffolded views using `grails generate-all *`.

At least, this is the way I did it in a couple of projects ;-)

Comment: This works well, and if you need to modify the scaffold, it's the only way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Change your non-scaffolded views to use a 'foo' layout, either by stating it explicitly in the `<head>` of each (non-scaffolded) GSP or by adding the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.sitemesh.default.layout = 'foo'
```

At this point, only the scaffolded pages will be using the 'main' layout and you can effectively make this an "empty" layout by changing it to something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <g:layoutHead/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The scaffolds do not appear to use the default layout. Even with this set, I'm seeing a sitemesh with the main layout.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `main.gsp` as your main layout. Rather, use `yourlayout.gsp`, manually set it in your GSPs, and then the sitemesh used will be the default, which is what you need for the scaffold.